# issues while trying npm run android

Tags: android, react-native

Hey so i have an school project to make a android app on "Space and outer world"
and I used react-native as the main framework but I kept having this error while trying to do "npm run android"

please lmk if you have a fix

```html
  1 error


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 747ms

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ android: `react-native run-android`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ android script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Aarnav\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-22T04_23_03_912Z-debug.log

C:\Users\Aarnav\Desktop\Space App\reactSpaceIntroduction>emulator -list-avds
'emulator' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Did you follow exactly the steps from React Native document? I think you missed some steps when setting up Android environment. https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

Comment: i did! idk what im missing :(